# Stripe payment processing with CardinalCommerce

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, payment-processing

Current app is using CardinalCommerce + Cybersource for 3DS and I'm switching to using Stripe instead

Q: Can I keep using CardinalCommerce and somehow pass the paRes (the 64Base encoded response from CardinalCommerce) to Stripe to satisfy the 3DS step?

Comment: I don't think they have anything available publicly that would do this. You can try your luck and ask their support team (https://support.stripe.com/contact) to see if they have any other suggestions/workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

Stripe support say there is no current support for this use-case, it's either Stripe or CardinalCommerce